# How to tie up multiple projects from same solution (not using Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have 3 projects in my c# solution which I want to run one after another. The 3 projects to share few things that I need to setup when I run the solution for ex. 2 projects write files (with same extension) and third project will compare these files. SO, at the start of solution I will specify where projects 1 and 2 should write and will also tell project 3 to pick up files from these location to compare.

How can I tie these projects, one option which I am exploring currently is msbuild, but not sure if there is any other better approach?
Can someone please give suggestions/advice ?

Comment: Is there any reason u don't want to use VS? There are free versions of Visual Studio. There are even versions for Mac and Linux

Comment: I want to reduce the dependency from visual studio incase it is not avilable , one example come to my mind is our build servers. They don't have the Visual studio installed, if use Visual studio not sure it will work there. I have very less experience on C# and VS so please correct if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tie these projects, one option which I am exploring currently is msbuild, but not sure if there is any other better approach? Can someone please give suggestions/advice ?

The simple way to resolve this issue is using project references in Visual Studio. Even if you don`t have Visual Studio installed in you build server. That because **MSBuild support project references and project dependencies, which can be used to choose the solution build order** (*VS uses MSbuild as build system, so VS 'supports' project references too, Thanks stijn comment.*).

After add project reference to the third project, unload and edit the third project file, you will find below statement in the `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\ReferencedProjectName\ReferencedProjectName.csproj">
    <Project>{bac2b43a-4cfc-45bb-a6bd-bde67d145af9}</Project>
    <Name>ReferencedProjectName</Name>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

When you build the solution with MSBuild, MSBuild will read this info, then determine the build order. So even if we don't have the Visual studio installed on the build, we could also have the build order with project references when we use MSBuild to build the solution.

Besides, if tie up multiple projects without using Visual Studio is your persistence, I would like provide you a workaround to resolve the build order, add a target to the third project to build other projects first:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
     <SolutionDir>$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($(MSBuildProjectDirectory)))</SolutionDir>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildBinPath)\MSBuild.exe&quot; &quot;$(SolutionDir)\ReferencedProjectName1\ReferencedProjectName1.csproj&quot;" />
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(MSBuildBinPath)\MSBuild.exe&quot; &quot;$(SolutionDir)\ReferencedProjectName2\ReferencedProjectName2.csproj&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Then only need build the third project in the build server: `MSBuild.exe ThirdProjectName\ThirdProjectName.csproj`

Comment: Your bold line is a bit confusing. What happens in reality is: MSbuild supports project references, and VS uses MSbuild as build system, so yes VS 'supports' project references.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Thanks for the reply, just one addition to the problem which I described. I also need to pass filename for proj 1 and 2 and then use the same ones in project 3. I fine this very simple to do with MSBuild using properties. Can we do the same via VS ?

Comment: @user85, yes, you can use MSBuild Properties in the project file of project 3 to include the filename for proj 1 and 2, like <PropertyGroup> <filename1>xxx</filename1> </PropertyGroup>. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx. Besides, if above answer resolve you question, you can mark it as answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues. If not, please let me know the latest info about this issue, I will keep follow